# Send multiple data in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, push-notification

Code

```
const payload ={
notification: {
title: '${userName}',
body: "You have recieved a new Message",
icon: "default",
click_action : "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
},
data : {
         from_user_id : from_user_id;
         from_user_name : userName
}
};
```

Getting an unexpected token for ',' 
but when i remove it i'm getting an error for 'from_user_name'... i guess the error lies in separating the 2 data... can someone help me out please

Comment: See: [When is it appropriate to tag multiple languages in my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354931/when-is-it-appropriate-to-tag-multiple-languages-in-my-question)

Comment: `from_user_id;` -> `from_user_id,`

Comment: fromuserid and name are seperate datas... my question i how do i seperate them

Comment: In JSON you separate value with a `,`. So `from_user_id : from_user_id,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON format will be like that:

```
const payload ={
notification: {
title: '${userName}',
body: "You have recieved a new Message",
icon: "default",
click_action : "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
},
data : {
         from_user_id : from_user_id,
         from_user_name : userName
}
};
```